# Binary adding with dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c, string, binary, malloc, realloc

*After a long time I'm playing with dynamic memory allocation in C and I'm encountering some issues with memory leaks ... I just can't see where the problem might be. Can Anyone help please?*

**EDIT2:
The program now works fine even with very large numbers and is quite quick :) I decided to change the program structure and used struct instead of just char string. There should not be any memory leaks (tested with valgrind).**

Current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct binary{
    char * number;
    size_t length;
}Tbinary;

//exterminate leading zeros
size_t exterminate(char * bin, size_t length){
char * pch = NULL;
long position = 0;

pch = strchr(bin, '1');
if(pch==NULL){
    bin[1] = '\0';
    length = 2;
}
else{
    position = pch-bin;
    strcpy(bin, pch);
}

return (length-position);
}

int binaryAdd(Tbinary first, Tbinary second){
int a=0, b=0, sum=0, carry=0;
size_t index = first.length;
first.number[first.length] = '\0';

while((first.length != 0) || (carry != 0)){
    if(first.length>1) a= first.number[first.length-2]-'0';
    else a = 0;
    if(second.length>1) b= second.number[second.length-2]-'0';
    else b = 0;
    sum = (a+b+carry)%2;
    first.number[first.length-1] = (sum)+'0';
    carry = (a+b+carry)/2;
    if(first.length >0)first.length--;
    if(second.length >0)second.length--;
}

exterminate(first.number,index);

printf("Sum: %s\n", first.number);
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int get_number(Tbinary *bin_addr){
char * tmp, * bin;
char ch=1;
int size = 1, index = 0;
bin = bin_addr->number;

while(ch){
    ch = getc(stdin);

    if((ch == '\n') || (ch == ' ')) ch = '\0';

    if((ch-'0' != 0) && (ch-'0' != 1) && (ch != '\0')) return EXIT_FAILURE;

    if (size-1 <=index){
        size += 5;
        tmp = (char *)realloc(bin, size*sizeof(char));
        if(tmp == NULL){
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        bin = tmp;
        bin_addr->number = bin;
    }
    bin[index++] = ch;
}

bin_addr->length = index;
bin_addr->length = exterminate(bin_addr->number, bin_addr->length);

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
} 

int main (void)
{
Tbinary bin1 = {bin1.number = NULL, bin1.length = 0};
Tbinary bin2 = {bin2.number = NULL, bin2.length = 0};

//allocate space for first number
bin1.number = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
if(bin1.number == NULL)
    return EXIT_FAILURE;

//allocate space for second number
bin2.number = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
if(bin2.number == NULL){
    free(bin1.number);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

printf("Enter two binary numbers:\n");

//number1 load
if(get_number(&bin1) != EXIT_SUCCESS){
    free(bin1.number);
    free(bin2.number);
    printf("Invalid input.\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

//number2 load
if(get_number(&bin2) != EXIT_SUCCESS){
    free(bin1.number);
    free(bin2.number);
    printf("Invalid input.\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

//add the two numbers
if(bin1.length >= bin2.length){
    if(binaryAdd(bin1, bin2) != EXIT_SUCCESS){
        free(bin1.number);
        free(bin2.number);
        printf("Invalid input.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
}
else{
    if(binaryAdd(bin2, bin1) != EXIT_SUCCESS){
        free(bin1.number);
        free(bin2.number);
        printf("Invalid input.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
}

free(bin1.number);
free(bin2.number);
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: 1) please attach your code here for future reference.
2) what exactly are the issues with the code you are mentioning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an off-by-one error in your `size` and `index` relationship:

```
    if (size <=index){
        size += 5;
        tmp = (char *)realloc(sum, size*sizeof(char));
        if(tmp == NULL){
            free(sum);  // free memory to avoid leak
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        sum = tmp;
    }
    for(int i=index; i>0; i--){
        sum[i] = sum[i-1];
    }
    sum[0] = num%2+'0';
    carry = num/2;
    index++;
}
sum[index] = '\0';
```

If, on entering the last iteration, `index == size-1`, you are writing outside the allocated memory. Sometimes that can be harmless, for others you may overwrite some important data without causing an immediate crash, and sometimes it can cause an immediate crash (when the out-of-bounds access crosses a page boundary, usually). Change the test to `size - 1 <= index`.

In `get_number`, if you need to `realloc`, you only change the local copy of the `char*` to the input buffer, so if the location changes, the pointer in `main` points to invalid memory. It should be

```
int get_number(char **bin_addr){
    char * tmp, bin = *bin_addr;
    char ch=1;
    size_t size = 1, index = 0;

    while(ch){
        ch = getc(stdin);

        if((ch == '\n') || (ch == ' ')){
            ch = '\0';
        }

        if((ch-'0' != 0) && (ch-'0' != 1) && (ch != '\0')){
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        if (size-1 <=index){
            size += 5;
            tmp = (char *)realloc(bin, size*sizeof(char));
            if(tmp == NULL){
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
            bin = tmp;
            *bin_addr = bin;  // let the pointer always point to the real block
        }
        bin[index++] = ch;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

and be called `get_number(&bin1);` in `main`.

Comment: Thanks, still Valgrind says there is allocated memory on program exit and very large numbers tend to crash the program, I think it's still something with the memory allocation

Comment: You should free `sum` if the `realloc` fails, though I don't expect that to happen unless you feed it really gigantic inputs. For `get_number`, you must pass the address of the `char*`.

Answer (score 1):

In binaryAdd() you should free sum after realloc() in all cases, not just when realloc() returns null. Same thing in get_number().
About `a = (int)strlen(first);` why cast the return of strlen() into an int?
Also, don't cast the return of allocation functions.

Comment: I don't think there shoult be a free after realloc since it changes the size of the memory block, but doesn't create one. ( http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/realloc/ )